# Evauating response to $x(n) = \sin{2\pi\frac{1}{4}n}$ given the system function

Tags: frequency, frequency-response, transfer-function

> Let the input signal $x(n) = \sin{2\pi\frac{1}{4}n}$ go in to the system described by: $$y(n) - y(n-1)+\frac{3}{16}y(n-2) =x(n).$$
>   What is the output signal?

I've calculated the system function $H(z)$ to:
$$H(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}+\frac{3}{16}z^{-2}}.$$
But I don't know how to proceed. The book does the following:

$$H(w=2\pi\frac{1}{4}) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-i2\pi\frac{1}{4}} + \frac{3}{16}e^{-i2\frac{\pi}{4}2}} = 0.776e^{-i0.888}$$

I am not entirely sure where this comes from. Why can I put in the frequency in a function of $z$?

Comment: Because sine waves are on the unit circle of the z-plane. $z = e^{j \omega}$

Answer (score 1):

You can start from `z-transform` of `sine`:

$ Z[sin(2\pi f n)\cdot u(n)](z)= \frac{z \cdot sin(2 \pi f)}{z^2-2z \cdot cos(2 \pi f)+1}$

For your signal you have $f=1/4$ and substituting you obtain:

$ X(z)=\frac{z}{z^2+1} $

The output of the system will be:

$Y(Z)=X(Z) \cdot H(Z) = \frac{z}{z^2+1} \cdot \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}+\frac{3}{16}z^{-2}} $

Computing the inverse transform you will obtain:

$ y(n)=Z^{-1}[Y(z)](n)=\frac{2}{425} ((-64 + 52 i) (-i)^n - (64 + 52 i) i^n - 25 4^{(-n)} + 17 \cdot 3^{(n + 2)} 4^{(-n)})$

That I computed with `wolfram alpha` but you can solve it from yourself with `partial fraction decomposition`. Also if appears the $i$ coefficient the succession is not `complex` because is real for each `integer` $n \geq 0 $

The method used by your book uses the conversion from `z-transform` to `dft` ($ z=exp(j 2 \pi f)$ ):

$ X(z) \longrightarrow X(exp(j 2 \pi f)) $

The dft of digital sine is a train of Kronecker  Delta so the only part that remains doing the multiplication $ X(f) \cdot H(f) $ is $H(f)$ calcutated in $f=1/4+k$ and you can compute the `idft` of $H(exp(j 2 \pi (1/4+k))) $ to obtain the result.

But I think that its solution misses the $k$ that should be $\{0;1/2\}$ because the dft should be symmetric respect $f=0.5$ `Nyquist frequency` otherwise the idft begin complex. I don't know if the book defines an half dft for real signals. Also phase misses because sin has a phase of $\pi /2$ that it doesn't consider. I don't know exactly what is it doing, maybe it wants work with `overlapping effects` and the question misses other effects that need to be summed at this to perform the correct result.